# What is the tapered cone on the B747 CF6 engine inlet cowling?

Tags: feature-identification, boeing-747, inlet

B747 and B767s are supposed to be using exact same GE CF6 engine, and as such their components are interchangeable including inlet cowl as they show to be effective in the IPC.

However some of the 747 cowls have this tapered cone on them:

[image]

That I have never seen on a 767-300s cowls. What is the function of that cone and what is it called?

Comment: The title question and the body don't match...

Comment: @Bianfable its for the GE CF6 engines

Comment: @RonBeyer I will modify it and let me know if its fits better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [image]
> — [twitter.com](https://twitter.com/doc7austin/status/962768547050147845) [cropped]

> [image]
> — [twitter.com](https://twitter.com/astro95media/status/855877952294223873) [cropped]

That cone is a fairing for a smooth transition to the pylon as shown above (both CF6 on 747-400).